# PHP is not removing files due to directory or files not being found

Tags: php

I'm running into a bit of an issue. I'm trying to remove all files from a directory and then remove the directory itself as `rmdir` won't delete an non-empty directory. However, when I try, it is saying it cannot find the files specified even though it is returning them with the `glob` function.

Here is my code:

```
 $store_files = glob(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
 $category_files = glob(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' .  $store_name . '/' . $category . '/items/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);



 foreach ($category_files as $cfiles) {
    unlink(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name . '/' . $cfiles);
 }

 foreach ($store_files as $file) {
    unlink(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' .  $owner_id . '/' . $store_name . '/' . $category . '/items/' . $file);
 }


 rmdir(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name);

 return true;
```

but the error message I am getting in the logs is:

```
    [Tue Jul 30 13:35:04.611780 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 12952:tid 1944] [client ::1:59713] PHP Warning:  unlink(C:\\xampp\\htdocs/public/images/uploads/store/3/Jimmy's Store/Computers/items/C:\\xampp\\htdocs/public/images/uploads/store/3/Jimmy's Store/Jimmy's_Store_cover.jpg): No such file or directory in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Classes\\User.php on line 494, referer: http://localhost/user
[Tue Jul 30 13:35:04.611780 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 12952:tid 1944] [client ::1:59713] PHP Warning:  rmdir(C:\\xampp\\htdocs/public/images/uploads/store/3/Jimmy's Store): Directory not empty in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Classes\\User.php on line 498, referer: http://localhost/user
```

I'm not sure why it is doing this to be honest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Oh, I did check the paths and that is the path to the directory + files.

Thanks!

Update:

Per the one answer to my question (which did work, as I suspected), it only removes from one directory but I need to remove files from multiple sub directories then remove the root directory. Here is the code I currently have in place:

```
 // then delete the files inside the category/items directory then remove the store folder
$store_files = glob(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name . '/*');

$category_files = glob(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name . '/' . $category . '/items/*');

foreach ($category_files as $file) {
    if (is_file($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}

foreach ($store_files as $files) {
    if (is_file($files)) {
        unlink($files);
    }
}


rmdir(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name);
```

For some reason, it is not deleting the files located in the `$category/items/` directory, thus I am running into the `rmdir` not empty PHP error. I know that path is correct, which is even more confusing. For some reason, it is returning an empty array with the files inside the category_name/items/ directory even though there is files inside the items directory.

Comment: Your paths are a bit wonky: `C:\\xampp\\htdocs/public/images/uploads/store/3/Jimmy's Store/Computers/items/C:\\xampp\\htdocs/public/images/uploads/store/3/Jimmy's Store/Jimmy's_Store_cover.jpg` You have C:\\ twice, and the quote may be throwing things off.

Comment: It also looks like you're mixing up which loop should use `$category_files` and which should use `$store_files`

Comment: @aynber its cause I'm using realpath with getcwd.. using zf2

Comment: Try `var_dump($cfiles)` and `var_dump($file)` inside of your foreach loops. Most likely they already have the full path, so you don't need to path creation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you loop through the file paths, you're appending `$cpath` to the other path. When looping the files returned, `$cpath` is a full path and doesn't need to be appended to folder locations. Try just doing

```
foreach ($category_files as $cfiles) {
    unlink($cfiles);
 }
```

Updated:

It looks like you're trying to remove all files within a directory as well as the root folder. In order to remove the folder, all files within it must be deleted. [Based on this article](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-delete-all-files-from-a-folder/), you can do a recursive loop on all files and directories within a folder to delete everything in a folder. The following code should work to delete everything in the folder and then remove the folder. You shouldn't need two for loops to delete files.

```php
// Get the directory with * selector for all files
$deleteDirectory = glob(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name . '/*');

//Loop through the file list.
foreach($deleteDirectory as $file){
    //Make sure that this is a file and not a directory.
    if(is_file($file)){
        //Use the unlink function to delete the file.
        unlink($file);
    }
}

//Finally, remove the directory
rmdir(realpath(getcwd()) . '/public/images/uploads/store/' . $owner_id . '/' . $store_name)
```

Comment: I get that but I have images in both directories

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out when I get home

Comment: yes but I have another two directories inside of the store name folder, I need to empty those two as they will contain files/directories.

Comment: yes, it deletes the files inside the one directory but i need to get to all of the directores (category_name/items/) to delete the files inside.

Comment: so I'm really not sure why it isn't deleting the files inside the category_name/items folder.. I'm getting no warnings or errors, its just returning an empty array when I use `var_dump($category_files)`..

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out, I had an extra whitespace character I was unaware. `ltrim` fixed it. Thanks for the answer though, it did help!